# Mod rewrite problem: rewrite url with drupal

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

Im am working on a drupal website with acqui solar search. I have to use this url /search/apachesolr_search/, but I want to change it to 'search' instead.

If u create an alias, my search doesn't work anymore...

Can someone help met to write a function for the 'Mod rewrite' module or give another option?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, using the menu_hook and callbacks.

You can read more about it [here.](http://evolvingweb.ca/story/apache-solr-mastery-how-add-custom-search-paths-hookmenu)